# How do I parse huge XML files with Ruby containing different tags?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

I have several big XML files, like this:

```
<Listings>
  <Listing>
    <Location>
      <StreetAddress>123 Main St</StreetAddress>
      <UnitNumber>2F</UnitNumber>
      <City>Anytown</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>10000</Zip>
    </Location>
  </Listing>
  <!-- a bajillion more Listing nodes -->
</Listings>
```

The main different between the different flavors is that one has a `<Listing>` node and another calls it `<property/>`. The nesting of child elements also varies.

What's a good way to parse a series of big XML files, each containing similar entries but with different tag names? I imagine that maintaining a mapping table of tag names makes sense, but how do you iterate through these efficiently with Ruby?

I'd like to grab the `<Listing>` elements, parse out their child elements like `StreetAddress`, etc. and them write them out somewhere else. The files each contain thousands of listings, some are 100+MB.

Comment: give one sample,then ask what you want. We can’t imagine.

Comment: Added a sample listing XML, sorry

Comment: The general rule of thumb is if you have a bajillion nodes or more, you should use the SAX or Reader interface so as to not hog all your memory. :)

Comment: checkout this sax parsing options, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/ New OX ruby parser seems to be 5 times faster than Nokogiri, https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri will accept more than one expression, for example:

```
doc.search('Listing', 'property').each do |item|
  puts item.at('StreetAddress', 'othernameforaddress').text
end
```

The file size issue might be a bigger problem though. If you don't have enough memory you might look into SAX

Comment: CSS allows using `search('Listing, property')` also, where the selector is all in one string.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Nokogiri or REXML and XPath like this:

```
//*[self::Listing or self::property]
```

So code will be something like this using Nokogiri:

```
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri.XML <<-XML
  <Listings>
    <Listing>
      <Location>
        <StreetAddress>123 Main St</StreetAddress>
        <UnitNumber>2F</UnitNumber>
        <City>Anytown</City>
        <State>NY</State>
        <Zip>10000</Zip>
      </Location>
    </Listing>
    <property>
      <Location>
        <StreetAddress>321 Main St</StreetAddress>
        <UnitNumber>2F</UnitNumber>
        <City>Anytown</City>
        <State>NY</State>
        <Zip>10000</Zip>
      </Location>
    </property>
  </Listings>
XML

doc.xpath("//*[self::Location or self::property]").map do |node|
  node.xpath("./*[self::StreetAddress or self::AlternativeStreetAddress]").text
end

# => ["123 Main St", "321 Main St"]
```

Comment: Notice that `xpath` is twice faster than `css` or `search` traversing:  https://gist.github.com/ixti/c78acb425808c3ddb326. Other than that, @pguardiario has a good point on SAX.